# Flutter/Dart: Excel Date to Date Object

Tags: excel, flutter, dart

I am parsing an excel document in excel using the excel: ^1.1.5 package. In my sheet, i have a Date column and this Date is being received in my Flutter code in the following format

"44663"

rather than:

"2022/04/12"

How do I parse this to a format such as YY-MM-DD.

I have tried `DateTime.parse()`, but it throws an error that my date format is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer :

```
const gsDateBase = 2209161600 / 86400;
const gsDateFactor = 86400000;

  final date = double.tryParse("44663");
  if (date == null) return null;
  final millis = (date - gsDateBase) * gsDateFactor;
  print(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(millis.toInt(), isUtc: true));
```